# tfs error when trying to checkin in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, tfs-2015

I am getting an error when I am trying to do a checkin from Visual Studio 2015:

Error:

> The process cannot access the file 'C:\projects\dbproject\dbproject.jfm' because it is being used by another process.

I have tried to reboot, and to delete the file but I have the same issue. Can I use the other tools to checkin my changes? or maybe somebody knows how to fix this issue?

Comment: Is there a file with a .sqlproj extension  in your Included Changes ?

Comment: @gencklavyeler No

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Please check and kill the processes which are using this file.
2. Exclude the file and any related files, exclude checkin the files, set ignore in 
   [`.gitignore`](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/git/tutorial/ignore-files#use-gitignore-to-prevent-tracking-of-files)  or [`.tfignore`](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/add-files-server#customize-which-files-are-ignored-by-version-control) file.
3. If that still not work, you can try using WinPE or any other tools
   to delete the file (backup first in case encounter any other issues)

Comment: It heped me. I created a .tfignore file and add jfm file to it. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Right click the dbproject.jfm which listed in Included Changes click to Exclude and try again checkin

[image]

Comment: i dont have this file in changes

Comment: than you can  see that https://github.com/github/gitignore/pull/2104 and can you add your Changes to question  , Someone is using the dbproject.jfm